# "For a polynomial equation with rational coefficients , irratonal roots occur in pairs"

Tags: polynomials

What is wrong in the above statement? Is it a valid one for all polynomials?
For example, consider the polynomial $$x^3-2=0$$
This has **only one irrational root** $\sqrt[3]{2}$ and two other imaginary roots.
For which type of polynomials the above statement is valid? Also please suggest a correct statement that would be more general.

Comment: $x^2+1=0$ has no irrational roots. Does this count as "occuring in pairs"? A pair for me is at least $2$ numbers.

Comment: A related statement which can be proved by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulashttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas: For a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb Q$ (or even $\mathbb Q(i)$) there cannot exist a single root in $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ (or $\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb Q(i)$) of multiplicity $1$.

Comment: The polynomial $x^3-3x+1$ has rational coefficients and three real zeros, all irrational. They are $2\cos(2\pi/9)$, $2\cos(4\pi/9)$ and $2\cos(8\pi/9)$.